# how do I insert a Js array in sqlite database in node

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, sqlite

I am new to this field and just started my first project and I am using sqlite3 as a database

```
// can insert this array as a row
var myArray = ["bob","16","student","Bosh University","football",]
```

this is my code... i have created the table already

```
let infoTable = new sqlite3.Database('./all/infoTable.db', (err) => {
  if (err) console.error(err.message)
});

infoTable.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS infoTable (name TEXT, age INTEGER, status TEXT, workPlace TEXT , intrest TEXT)`)
```

can I insert this array as a row into the dataBase???

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```js
var myArray = ["bob","16","student","Bosh University","football"];
infoTable.run('\
INSERT INTO \
  infoTable(name TEXT, age INTEGER, status TEXT, workPlace TEXT , intrest TEXT) \
VALUES \
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', ...myArray);
```

They have a good [API Reference](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki).

Comment: yeah i did go through but i am really new to programming itself and there are alot of thing named 'name' on the syntax page, soo i got confused... thank you so much anyway

Comment: Although this works, I'd suggest storing the data in named variables first or to refactor into using object with keys to prevent future bugs such as adding a column in the middle and having a bad order in the input array which would result in a column mismatch :-)

Comment: @jave.web Sure, you just have to make sure of the method you're using. If I'm not mistaken, mysql2 methods don't support object key binding in queries, but Sequelize does.